# How to get all cells from UICollectionView given a specific row indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Are there any way to get all cells on the row from UICollectionView given the indexPath.row?

Comment: show what you did yet.

Comment: Nothing. Currently I am in the middle of brainstorming and researching on what approach should I take

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can make something like this:

```
var itemsInRow1: [Int] = [1,2,3]
var cellsInRow: [Cells] = []
for item in 0..<itemsInRow1 {
    cellsInRow.append(collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath.init(row: item, 
              section: 0)))
}
```

But i guess it depends on how you have your `dataSourceModel` setup

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method. You have to mathematically calculate according to the collection view width and some calculation according to the row number you enter.

Comment: I see. I thought of the same thing, but wouldn't it be slow if I have huge data source?